# A general notion of the support of a measure?

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a finite measure space. If $\Omega$ is finite and $\mathcal A = 2^\Omega$, then the *support* of $\mu$ is $s(\mu) = \{\omega: \mu\{\omega\} > 0\}$.

As far as I know, there isn't a very broad generalization of $s(\mu)$ to uncountable $\Omega$. The most common approach seems to involve assuming that $\Omega$ comes equipped with a topology $\mathcal T$ that generates $\mathcal A$. One then defines $$s(\mu) = \{\omega: \omega \in U \in \mathcal T \implies \mu(U) > 0\}.$$
That is, $\omega$ is in the support of $\mu$ if every open set containing $\omega$ has positive $\mu$-measure. This definition coincides with the one for the finite case when $\mathcal T$ is the discrete topology.

It seems to me that it would be nice to have a general notion of support that doesn't rely on $\Omega$ having a topology. Here is an idea I had.

Say that a measure $\mu$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal A)$ is *discrete* if it is of the form $\mu = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \delta_{\omega_i}$ with $\alpha_i$ positive and $\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i = 1$, and where $\delta_{\omega_i}$ is point mass at $\omega_i$.

The general definition of support that I will propose is motivated by the following interesting fact:

> Every finitely additive finite measure on $(\Omega, \mathcal A)$ is the pointwise limit of a net of discrete measures. That is, for all $\mu$ there is a net $(\mu_d)$ of discrete measures such that $\mu(A) = \lim_d \mu_d(A)$ for all $A \in \mathcal A$.

Let $\mathcal P$ be the set of all finitely additive measures on $(\Omega, \mathcal A)$ equipped with the topology of pointwise convergence.

> Now say that $\omega$ is in $s(\mu)$ if and only if every open subset of $\mathcal P$ containing $\mu$ contains a discrete measure $\nu = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \delta_{\omega_i}$ such that $\omega_i = \omega$ for some $i$.

It's clear that this definition of support generalizes the one given when $\Omega$ is finite. And while it does utilize some topology (on $\mathcal P$), it doesn't assume that $\Omega$ is a topological space, and can therefore be applied to any measure space whatsoever (even a finitely additive one).

> This is open-ended, but my question is basically: Is this a good definition of support? Has it been studied before? Does anyone have any interesting observations or comments about the definition?

---

One potentially interesting observation is that on any space there will always be finitely additive measures $\mu$ with *full support*, i.e. $s(\mu) = \Omega$.

*Proof.* Suppose not. Then for every $\mu \in \mathcal P$ there is an open subset $N_\mu$ of $\mathcal P$ and $\omega_\mu \in \Omega$ such that no discrete measure $\nu = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \delta_{\omega_i}$ in $N_\mu$ is such that $\omega_i = \omega_\mu$ for some $i$. The collection $\{N_\mu: \mu \in \mathcal P\}$ is an open cover of $\mathcal P$, and thus for some $n$ and $\mu_1,...,\mu_n$ the collection $\{N_{\mu_i}: 1 \leq i \leq n\}$ covers $\mathcal P$ because $\mathcal P$ is compact ($\mathcal P$ is a closed subset of $[0,1]^\mathcal A$ with the product topology.) But now for any positive $\alpha_i$, $1 \leq i \leq n$, summing to $1$ the discrete measure $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \delta_{\omega_{\mu_i}}$ is not in any of the $N_{\mu_i}$, which is a contradiction.

This raises the question:

> Under what conditions can one guarantee that there is a *countably additive* measure with full support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your definition correctly, I think every measure (including the zero measure) has full support.  Here is why:  given any measure
$\mu$, and any point $\omega $ on $\Omega $, let's prove that $\omega $ lies in the support of $\mu $.  For this pick any open subset $V$ of
$\mathcal P$ containing $\mu $.

By definition of the topology of pointwise
convergence, there is some $\varepsilon >0$,  and  measurable sets $A_1, A_2, \ldots , A_n$, such that
$$
  U_{\varepsilon ;A_1, A_2, \ldots , A_n}:= \{\nu \in  \mathcal P: |\nu (A_i)-\mu (A_i)|<\varepsilon ,  \text{ for } i=1, \ldots , n\}\subseteq  V.
  $$

We will now prove that there exists a discrete measure $\nu $ in $V$ such that $\nu (\omega )\neq 0$.

Using your claim, pick  some discrete measure $\nu $ in $U_{\varepsilon /2;A_1, A_2, \ldots , A_n}$.
If $\nu (\omega )\neq 0$, we are done.  Otherwise,
let
$$
  \nu '= \nu +(\varepsilon /2)\delta _\omega .
  $$
It is then clear that $\nu '(\omega )=\varepsilon /2\neq 0$, and for every $i$ we have
$$
  |\nu '(A_i)-\mu (A_i)| \leq  |\nu '(A_i)-\nu (A_i)| +   |\nu (A_i)-\mu (A_i)| < (\varepsilon /2)\delta _w(A_i) + \varepsilon /2 \leq \varepsilon ,
  $$
This proves that $\nu '$ belongs to $V$.

Comment: Rats! You’re right